# Django: Session_Cookie_Age

Tags: python, django, django-sessions

Assuming I set `request.session['discount'] = discount_code` and `Session_Cookie_Age` is set to two weeks. Is the session discount always renewed whenever I reload the page for another two weeks? Or can I set expiry dates individually?